# Finding the spectral representation of the Delta function given the Green function of an operator

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, spectral-theory

I'm working through the problems of a book on Sturm-Liouville problems. In a problem I found the Green function for the following SLP2  problem

$$\frac{-d^2g}{dx^2}-\lambda g=\delta(x-\xi)$$
$$g(0,\xi)=g(2\pi,\xi)$$
$$\frac{dg(0,\xi)}{dx}=\frac{dg(2\pi,\xi)}{dx}$$

as

$$g(x,\xi)=-\frac{\cos{(\sqrt{\lambda}(|x-\xi|-\pi))}}{2\sqrt{\lambda}\sin\sqrt\lambda \pi}$$

Now in the next problem it wants me to prove that "using the above Green function, *the spectral representation for Delta function* is this":

$$\delta(x-\xi)=\frac{1}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\cos nx \cos n\xi + \sin nx \sin n\xi )$$

I have no idea how to start solving this. Can you tell me from where should I start solving this?

Comment: A spectral representation means to express the dirac delta in a series (here it will be just a Fourier series) where the basis-functions are the eigenfunctions (here something like $\sim \cos(nx)$) of the differential operator in question. What you seem to be missing is to determine all the allowed eigenvalues $\lambda$ for the problem (which should be just the integers $n$ here).

Comment: Another, more direct way, to prove the formula here is to compute the $[-\pi,\pi]$ Fourier series of $\delta(x)$ the standard way, i.e. determine $c_k$ from the expansion $\delta(x) = c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_k \cos(nx)$.